# I have to wright a slideshow for a bank but when i change the picture when running it did not change

Tags: python, reload, autorun, python-3.11

its my code in slideshow2.py

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageTk
from time import sleep

# adjust window
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("200x200")

# loading the images


l = Label()
l.pack()

# using recursion to slide to next image
x = 1

img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("1.png"))
img2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("2.png"))
img3 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("3.png"))
img4 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("4.png"))
img5 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("5.png"))
# function to change to next image

def move():

    global x

    if x == 6:
        x = 1


    if x == 1:
        l.config(image=img)

    elif x == 2:
        l.config(image=img2)
   
    elif x == 3:
        l.config(image=img3)
       
    elif x == 4:
        l.config(image=img4)
    
    elif x == 5:
        l.config(image=img5)

    x = x + 1
    root.after(2000,move)




# calling the function
move()

root.mainloop()
```

and five picture
[image: these are the picture]
whit this picture (when i add it i change the name of it in 1,2,3,4 or 5.png[image: this image]

i try reloading package and back function ,loop and class but it show the previous image not new i want to the picture change whitout run again

Comment: Worked for me. Are you using macos?

Comment: no i am using windows and when you replace a image while running  it change

Comment: Absolutely, It changed. Using Windows 10

Comment: But i am using windows 10

Comment: what editor or ide are you using

Comment: Pythom 3.12.0b3